# Trying to make sense of some JLPT practice questions

Tags: grammar, jlpt

Last year's JLPT tests were made available for download recently, and so to gauge my progress and plan what to study I decided to take the N2 test.  I'm right at the threshold of passing (58% overall raw score), so this is in large part an effort to try and figure out how to pick up some points in a section that is killing me.

Specifically, it's the section of the test where they give you a sentence with four blanks and a star in the third blank.  Your objective is to put the clauses in answers 1-4 in order and choose the number corresponding to the starred spot.  Unfortunately the answer key only said which one was the right answer, so in the spots I missed I've got little way of telling where I went wrong.

The first question, and my accompanying logic when I took the test, are as follows.  Please help me understand where my logic is off.

> 問い１： 不調だった山中【やまなか】選手がついにゴールを決めた。彼に_**_ __** * *_*_相当あったはずだ。
>
> 1. したら
> 2. という
> 3. プレッシャーは
> 4. 「もし、またミスしたら」

At the time I seem to have arranged them as 4-2-1-3, however the answer key said the correct answer was 2.  In light of that, would 3-4-2-1 be correct?  It seems like 2 has to come after 4 on account of the quotative particle と, but that's all I've got with certainty here.

Comment: 質問長すぎない？最初の２門すでに回答できてるけど疲れちゃった。分割できないかな？

Comment: とりあえず正解だけ。Q1 1-4-2*-3, Q2 2-4-1*-3, Q3 2-3-4*-1. For Q4, the correct sentence is 「子どもが（したい）（と思うことは）（やらせて）（やりたい）と思っている」。 For Q5, you're correct.

Comment: Apologies on account of the length; I'd debated whether to break it up or not and thought it'd come across as vote-whoring to drop too many separate questions at once.  That said, I really appreciate the assistance provided thus far!

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  Multi-questions like this don't work well with the SE format, so I'm going to edit out the extra questions.  Could you please repost them as separate questions so TN has a place to put all the answers he wrote?

Comment: @TokyoNagoya 「疲れちゃった」から？おじんかっｗｗｗ

Comment: @snailboat: 了解.  Will keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: @Chocolate せやないねん。母語話者として、問題の「回答」自体は考えなくても一瞬でわかるけど、その回答を日本語学習者の立場に立って説明するのがめっちゃ疲れるねん。自分では意識してやっていないことを説明するわけだから。わかる？わからんやろなあ・・・

Comment: @TokyoNagoya まあ・・・朝飯前のお茶の子さいさいって感じでやっていらっしゃるのかと思ってましたけど・・・

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer should be 1-4-2-3.

You have probably seen the common structure "〜〜という + Noun" before.  「と」 is a quotative particle so you have a good choice in #4 with quotation marks to precede it.  So, we have a 4-2 for a start.

The only choice that starts with a noun is #3, making a 4-2-3 an sure bet already.  The only thing you now need to think about is whether to put 「したら」 before or after the 4-2-3.

Since there is no such phrase 「プレッシャーはしたら」 possible, you would put 「したら」 in front of the 4-2-3.  「Person + にしたら」 makes perfect sense, meaning "to/for (person)", so 「彼にしたら」 sounds good.

Comment: I'd like to split up Kaji's question (although all I can really do is edit out the extra questions and wait for him to repost them).  Would you be willing to post your answers individually once he does so?  You'll get more reputation that way, since people will be able to upvote each answer :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem.